# Как проверить существование мьютекса

Tags: c++, winapi

у меня есть две программы в первой создаёться мьютекс

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE mutex = CreateMutexA(NULL, NULL, "MutexName");
    DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(mutex, 0);
    if(result == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        StartProg();
        ReleaseMutex(mutex);
    }
    CloseHandle(mutex);

}
```

Мне нужно что-бы при запуске второй программы она проверяла существование мьютекса из первой программы по имени т.е. проверила запущен ли мьютекс с именем `MutexName` и если запущен то ждать пока освободиться и продолжить своё выполнение. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вторым аргументов в этой функции выступает флаг обязательности создания объекта. Соответственно для получения желаемого эффекта необходимо попытаться создать объект в обязательном порядке:

```
LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES const p_attributes{};
BOOL const initial{TRUE};
HANDLE const mutex{::CreateMutexA(p_attributes, initial, "MutexName")};
if (NULL == mutex)
{
    auto const last_error{::GetLastError()};
    ::std::abort();
}
{
    auto const last_error{::GetLastError()};
    if (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS == last_error)
    {
        // мьютекс уже был создан ранее, ждем...
        auto const result{::WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE)};
    }

if (FALSE == ::CloseHandle(mutex))
{
    auto const last_error{::GetLastError()}:
    ::std::abort();
}
```

Comment: Параметр `bInitialOwner` определяет состояние мьютекса при создании и не влияет на поведение при уже существующем мьютексе (при любом значении параметра функция может открыть существующий мьютекс)

Comment: Так, уже вернее, но всё равно есть неточность. Параметр 'bInitialOwner' -- не флаг обязательности создания объекта, а его начальное состояние. Получить `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` при создании уже существующего мьютекса можно как при значении флага `TRUE`, так и при `FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

Функция `CreateMutexA` может создать или октрыть существующий мьютекс.

Отличить создала она мьютекс или открыла можно по `::GetLastError()`.

Один из редких случаев, когда результат, возвращаемый `::GetLastError()` определён для успешно выполнившейся Windows API функции (обычно он валиден только для неуспешных вызовов).